# PHP cookie randomly unsetting itself

Tags: php, cookies, ssl

Currently I am using PHP cookies to keep a login, it works fine locally and works fine on non-SSL sandboxes.  On a live SSL deployment the cookie randomly unsets itself and kicks me off the site.

I went in and dumped $_COOKIE with print_r() and it constantly showed the cookie values and did not kick me off the site.  After further testing all I needed to do to not be kicked off was echo an empty space in a hidden div on top of the HTML structure.  It works every time now.

Anyone have any idea why tricking the output is keeping the cookie?

```
setcookie('cookie', 'value', mktime(0,0,0,date('m'), date('d') + 1, date('Y')),'/');
```

Comment: Hard to say without know where in your code you are trying to set cookies.  One thing you do need to be aware of is that cookies MUST be set prior to providing any output to the browser (as cookies are sent to the browser in response headers).

Comment: For setting your time you should really be doing something like: `mktime().time()+60*60*24`

Comment: The intention is to have the cookie expire at midnight the day it was set not a full 24 hours from when it was set.  I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this and make sure you allow the cookie to be usable on a non-SSL connection AND SSL connection.

```
setcookie('cookie', 'value', gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()+86400),'/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'.', FALSE, TRUE);
```

Comment: still did not doing anything, i just output anything prior to the page output, which is built as a string and echoed all at once, and it works fine.  thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

WOW!  My bad.

This software is ran in installations and this particular installation had a missing favicon URL in it's config.  So the app was initiating from the entry page because of the empty favicon request.  Because the entry page was not meant to run when this cookie was set the request unset the cookie.

DOH!

Thanks for all responses, sorry to ask "stupid"? questions